# ruby rest-client content in the header / payload

Tags: ruby, rest, rubygems, rest-client

My request from the swagger is

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "version": "v15" \ 
 }' 'https://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/tools/v1/termsAndConditions'
```

My ruby code is

```
payload={                                                                        
   :multipart => true,                                                           
    }                                                                            
headers1 = {                                                                     
    :content_type => 'multipart/form-data',                                      
    :accept => 'application/json',                                               
     # -d ':version=> 'v16'                                                      

}                                                                                
     begin                                                                          
    response= RestClient::Request.execute(                                       
        :url => "https://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX/tools/v1/termsAndConditions",            
        :method => :post,                                                        
        :headers => headers1,                                                    
        :verify_ssl => false,                                                    
        :proxy => nil,                                                           
        :payload=>payload                                                        
    )                                                                            
  rescue RestClient::BadRequest => err                                           
    @responsebody=err.response.body                                              
    @responseCode="400"                                                          
  else                                                                           
    @responseCode=response.code                                                  
    @responsebody=response.body                                                  
    end
```

How do i pass below content in the header or payload to replicate swagger?

'-d '{ \ 
"version": "v15" \ 
}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d` is the data argument in your post request and it has nothing to do with `headers`.

```
payload={                                                                        
  version: 'v15',                                                           
}.to_json
```

and the rest of your code should be the same. I don't know why you need `:multipart => true` inside your payload.

Comment: i am getting below error after trying the code
{"message":"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"}

Comment: In your headers1 variable you need to set “Content-Type”: “application/json”